# Image height size is not as setted

Tags: html, css

I have a simple HTML site with some CSS buttons on it. The buttons working fine, but the top image height is not the size what i set to it.
I made the image originally to 800x190.
Also i set the code as this:

```css
#felkep1 {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 padding: 0px;
 z-index: -1;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 50%;
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div id="felkep1">
<img src="images/bg1.jpg" style="width:800px;height:190px;" />
</div>
```

And here is the image itself:
[background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QLxD.jpg)

And in final, here is the link to my website, where is visible the problem.
The button row is 50px high, and it's positioned to 140px from the top.
So basically both the image and the buttons bottom should be in the same px height.

[Rolnaashch website](http://rolnaashch.co.nf/)

I tried in both Chrome, and Firefox. Results are the same.

I searched the code over and over, but i have no clue now what i am missing or where!

Comment: Why don't you simply create a wrapper for your navigation and set the image as a background to it?

Comment: the image *is* 190px high. What would you like to achieve?

Comment: Your buttons are all positioned with `top: -25px` - _that_ is why the are not at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the answers and helps! I am not very experienced in HTML and CSS, i just learning it, so i don't have any knowledge about wrappers, i will look after it! :)
CBroe was right also with the answer below this together. I thought the background size is resized, but the translation messed up all things! I am so sorry for this n00b question, i really overlooked it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For #backs1 make `transform: translate(-50%, 0%);`
And for .btn-group .button remove `top` property. Problem is because of tanslate not being used correctly

Comment: Cool, this is it! Thank you very much for the pointing out! It's so awkward, a very silly mistake!